# How to share internet connection

Tags: wireless, internet, android, bluetooth

I have a LG P500 with Android 4.1 and I want to share internet connection(LAN) to it. I have USB cable(for phone), bluetooth dongle, wifi dongle(TL-WN821N) to use.

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to buy a WiFi router. Connect the router to your Internet. Setup a home WiFi access point at the router. Connect the phone to the WiFi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a reverse tethering. Take a look here [ http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2169920 ]